# Responsive Grid IE8

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a grid of 4x1 elements that wrap to 2x2 below a certain width I want to get rid of the padding left for the 3rd item in the 2x2 grid in IE8 I could use nth-child but that's IE9+

```
<section>
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div>
</section>

div{width:50%;padding-left:20px;float:left;}
div.first-child{padding-left:0;}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px){
  div{width:25%;}
}
```

Comment: You could maybe try something like following: [http://webdesignetc.co/faking-css-nth-child-support-in-ie8/](http://webdesignetc.co/faking-css-nth-child-support-in-ie8/) Or maybe something like: [http://selectivizr.com/](http://selectivizr.com/)

Comment: How are you making the HTML5 elements and media queries work in IE8?

Comment: Yes! either of those options will work thanx